# Duplicate with CSV does not work for images

Tags: image, csv, duplicate

I have a Question about the CSV import/export. Where the images do not duplicate from the already existing ones.

let me explain my issue:

I have to add 95 different products with each 3 or 4  differed images and prices. (these are flue gas pipes)
so I add these 95 products manually on the Magento dashboard system.
Now  I have to make the same 95 products in 80 / 100 / 130 / 150 / 180 / 200 / 250 / 300 mm Ø.

Here are the only differences: Name/SKU/Price/MFSRP/URL/ and some layered navigation attributes.

So I downloaded all my products >> Deleted all products besides the 95 flue gas products I need to change >> Did the “change all option” on row Name/SKU/URL to change 150mm in 130mm >> Did Copie/paste the new prices in it and saved it as a new document.

So far so good, but when I uploaded this list (ps. 0 errors) all the images where removed in each new product.

Info:

1.
The images got the exact same path as the working first manually made products. (nothing is changed in the name of the product)

Example 1 product:

_media_image

/m/f/mf100-sectie-100cm-info.png

/m/f/mf100-sectie-100cm-schets.png

/m/f/mf100-sectie-100cm_1.png

_media_lable

MF100-Sectie-100-cm-info

MF100-Sectie-100-cm-schets

MF100-Sectie-100-cm

2.
I manually added the around 300 images and image labels to the new uploaded products (took me 5 hours of brain death repeating a routine)  and now I got all the images duplicated in my FTP: /M/F/… so if I continue this path I will have 10 duplicates from each image on my sever. And I will have 50 more boring hours to go.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is how Magento works: it does not check if an uploaded or imported image is the same and always creates a new file.

To change this behavior, you would have to rewrite the media model. This free extension already does it: https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_ReuseImages

Comment: Hello Fschmengler, thank you for the fast reply. Do i understand it right that this is only an solution to save sever space? This still leaves me with 50 hours of uploading same images to products right?

Comment: Interesting, I thought you could reference existing image paths in the CSV. If not, you can copy the images to `media/import`, no need to upload them in the backend for each product.

Comment: i did a few test and found out how to get it working: when i download the datasheet i have to change for example: path /s/a/sample.jpg to /sample.jpg in this way the program changes it back to /s/a/sample_1.jpg and it works with the next duplicate. i wil try this weekend to use the extension to get rid of the image duplication. thanks for your help.